# Check element with class of active and slide down the next element beneath it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to check if the element with the class nav-title also has an active class, if true, slide down the next element (which has a class of .sub-nav) beneath the element with the nav-title class.

Otherwise if no element with the class of nav-title has an active class, find the first element with a class of .sub-nav, show it, go up, add the class of active to the .nav-title

---

The next code with the on-click functions works just fint, it's just the first one that doesn't.. i've tried to add the class active in the html document itself, but then both the first element and the second gets the class active and no sub nav gets slide down.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("#nav").find("nav-title").hasClass("active")) {
    $(this).next(".sub-nav").slideDown("fast");
  } else {
    $("#nav").find(".sub-nav:first").show().prev().addClass("active");
  }

  $("#nav").on("click", ".nav-title", function() {
    $('.active').removeClass("active").next(".sub-nav").stop().slideUp("fast");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(this).next(".sub-nav").stop().slideDown("fast");
  });
});
```

Can anybody help?

Also my html looks like this by the way:

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li class="nav-title">Title 1</li>
  <ul class="sub-nav">
    <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <li class="nav-title active">Title 2</li>
  <ul class="sub-nav">
    <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

My code might be a little messy, i'm just learning jquery as we speak.

Wooops! I made a little live example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/kcWA8/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `this` in this context the way that you think you can.  `this` inside of the `if` is not the nav.  You're also mising the `.` before `nav-title` in your `find`.  Do this instead:

```
if ($("#nav").find(".nav-title").hasClass("active")) {
    $("#nav .nav-title.active").next(".sub-nav").slideDown("fast");
}
```

Or:

```
var $active = $("#nav .nav-title.active");

if ($active.length > 0) {
    $active.next(".sub-nav").slideDown("fast");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, it worked just great, I used the first code you wrote and I can see why it makes sense. Do you guys think my code looks fine? Could it be optimized or something like that. Otherwise I will answer my question, because the solution has been found.

Comment: For questions on optimizing code, you might try http://codereview.stackexchange.com  One thing I can point out quickly, you should cache your jquery objects.  Rather than calling `$("#nav")` multiple times, assign it to a variable and re-use it to avoid re-querying the dom.  Similar to what I've done in my second code snippet.

Comment: Thanks a lot, makes perfect sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I used James Montagne's answer, it worked just fine, looks like I misunderstand this `(this)` and forgot a dot in front of my class.

Thanks!